# How to run grunt docular-server?

Tags: node.js, documentation, gruntjs, documentation-generation

if I execute the command `grunt docular-server`

I get the error message:

`ERROR:  Could not start node server [TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'server']`

then the docular-server is not running.

I installed grunt to make a documentation of my code like this:

```
 `npm install -g grunt-cli`
 `npm install grunt grunt-docular`
```

My `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

docular: {
groups: [],
showDocularDocs: true,
showAngularDocs: true
}

});

// Load the plugin that provides the "docular" tasks.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-docular');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['docular']);

};
```

this example is taken from the official site here:

http://grunt-docular.com/documentation/docular/docularinstall/installdocular

Answer (score 5):

The latest version as of right now is `docular@0.7.2`.

It is not very compatible with `grunt-docular@0.1.2`.

In order to get `grunt docular-server` to work, I had to go back to version `0.6.6` of `docular` in my `package.json` and run `npm install`.

Things started working after that for me.

See https://github.com/Vertafore/docular#new-beta-version for details.

Apparently, there is a new maintainer trying to get the project going again.

Comment: Running  `npm install grunt-docular@0.1.2; npm install docular@0.7.2; grunt docular-server` made things work for me too!

Comment: `grunt docular-server` didn't seem to work for me, I had better luck with `grunt docularserver`and following these other suggestions http://serverfault.com/a/632571/250574